# my docker application build failed in azure devops

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am having a sample dotnet web application with windows docker container. In local machine the application build, image build, container creation and running it is successful, but moving the same code to azure devops throwing a build error as below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(98,5):
Error : Building webapplication1 Service 'webapplication1' failed to build: 
a Windows version 10.0.17134-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host. 
For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting 

Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

The path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(98,5)
```

does not there in my machine. Can anyone explain and help me to fix the issue? 
Note: I have not used any customized build agent. Will this create an issue?

Comment: The line *a Windows version 10.0.17134-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host* precisely tells you what the issue is. Have you tried changing your `dockerfile` to use a 10.0.14393 image?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Daniel. But there is no issue in my local machine. After moving to azure devops the issue occurred. Yes you are right I can downgrade my docker windows version, but instead can I fix from azure devops side like if azure devops using any windows version to build the application can I upgrade the azure devops windows version and fix it. In real time development, downgrading docker windows version means again we should test our application in all scenarios and if anything fails because version compatibility  it will delay the build. Is my assumption correct??

Comment: If you're using a hosted agent, there's nothing you can do about it -- Microsoft provides the build environment, and you don't have control over it. If you want to use the hosted agent, you have to use a supported container. Otherwise, you'll have to provision your own build infrastructure and configure it however you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. If it is. Then I should follow the documentation of supporting versions and proceed with the development. Once again thanks for quick reply.